# Filtro de palavras

Tags: javascript

Como posso fazer um filtro de palavras em Javascript? Por exemplo, tenho uma `div` e dentro dessa `div` não quero que existam determinadas palavras que estão dentro de um array:

```
var badWords = ['teste', 'teste1', 'oteste2'];
```

Como faço para verificar se essas palavras existem no texto e substituir seu conteúdo de maneira que a primeira letra dessa palavra apareça, mas o restante fique com asteriscos?

Por exemplo:

```
<div>Este texto tem as palavras: teste, teste1 e oteste2, e eu quero filtrar as palavras teste, oteste1 e teste2</div>
```

O conteúdo acima seria substituído por algo assim:

```
<div>Este texto tem as palavras: t****, t***** e o******, e eu quero filtrar as palavras t****, t***** e o******</div>
```

Lembrando que não posso usar jQuery, precisaria ser em Javascript puro justamente porque não justifica usar a biblioteca completa só para fazer isso...

Comment: O que você tentou até agora?

Comment: @Beterraba Esse é o problema eu não sou experiente com Javascript, portanto tudo que tentei não resultou. O máximo que consegui foi encontrar o index dessas palavras, veja: http://pastebin.com/5tvXRj1c

Todos os outros testes falharam... Tentei .replace(), e outros...

Comment: Cara, estes textos são gerados como? em qual linguagem? Vem de um banco de dados? EU não usaria javascript para isto, se estiver desabilitado no navegador, já era seu filtro.

Comment: Os textos vem de uma página HTML comum amigo.. Nenhum banco de dados.

Comment: Mas e porque escrever palavras em HTML que serão filtradas? Não seria mais fácil não escrever o que não pode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar RegExp:

```
var arr = ['teste', 'teste1', 'oteste2'];
var f = document.querySelector('div').textContent;

arr.forEach(function(el, index, arr) {
    var regexp = new RegExp("\\b(" + el + ")\\b", "g");
    f = f.replace(regexp, el.substr(0,1) + el.substring(1).replace(/./g, "*"));
});

document.querySelector('div').textContent = f;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rErDW/1/)

Answer (score 6):

Vou deixar você se virar pra pegar a *div* e trocar a propriedade **innerHtml** ou **innerText** dela, já que você não quer usar jQuery.

De resto:

```
var badWords = { // Isso vai ser nosso dicionário.
    "teste": "t****",
    "teste1": "t*****",
    "oteste2": "o******",
    "Supercaligrafilistiespialidocio": "S******************************"
    /* etc, etc...*/
}

function changeWords (input) {
    var text = input.split(" "); // Isso pega a string de input e quebra em palavras separadas por espaços;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var word = text[i];
        if (badWords[word]) { // Essa é a sintaxe pra ver se algo está no dicionário
            text[i] = badWords[word];
        }
    }
    return text.join(" "); // Isso junta todas as palavras num texto de novo, separadas por espaços.
}
```

Comment: MaryPoppinsMention++;